# Can I write MySQL settings in drupal settings.php file?

Tags: database

I am using Drupal 7 and i am getting `MySQL server has gone away` error in my current site.
By doing Google i figured out that i need to increase some of the parameters of my.ini file

```
key_buffer
max_allowed_packet
table_cache 
sort_buffer_size
```

Is there any way that I can write this in Drupals settings.php?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, those need to be set in your MySQL server's my.ini/my.cnf file.

Those settings can't be changed on the fly from any process (PHP, Apache, even MySQL itself), you need to set them in the .ini/.cnf file and then restart the MySQL server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: my.ini in Windows, my.cnf in *nix.

Comment: @Citricguy Cheers, I've added that in